# Paypal and Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, paypal

I want to have a donation box via paypal in a sheet. When the sheet comes down a webview within the sheet loads the donation box website. I want to close the sheet when the user has completed the donation.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't trust putting any financial credentials in an app, especially if it's just for a donation.

My recommendation:  Have a textfield where they can put in an amount, but clicking the "Donate" button takes them to Paypal.com, where the information has been filled in for them, and all they have to do is click "Send Money".  That'd be much more reputable, IMO.  (Plus it's way easier to implement)